# Issue with join in Python

Tags: python, pandas, join, time-series

I am new to python and i have issue with joining two data frames.
dataframe dti is generated by me:

```
   Date1        Time1
0 2018-07-03   00:00:00
1 2018-07-03   00:15:00
2 2018-07-03   00:30:00
3 2018-07-03   00:45:00
4 2018-07-03   01:00:00
```

[dti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s65PB.png)

when i do dti.dtypes, i get the below answer

```
Out[175]:
Date1    object
Time1    object
dtype:   object
```

Now I have another data set temp1

```
  Date1          Time1    tmp
0 2018-07-03   00:00:00   97
1 2018-07-03   01:00:00   95
2 2018-07-03   02:00:00   93
3 2018-07-03   03:00:00   91
4 2018-07-03   04:00:00   90
```

[temp1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEsLz.png)

when i do temp1.dtypes, i get the below answer:

```
Date1    object
Time1    object
tmp       int64
dtype: object
```

Now I am trying to merge(left outer Join) both data sets, i am getting the cartasian product, but i dont want the crtesian product. I want the Date1 and Time1 from dti and tmp from temp1.

```
temp2 = pd.merge(dti,temp1,on=["Date1","Time1"],how = 'left', indicator=True)
```

this is the solution i am expecting:

```
   Date1        Time1      tmp
0 2018-07-03   00:00:00     97
1 2018-07-03   00:15:00     NaN
2 2018-07-03   00:30:00     NaN
3 2018-07-03   00:45:00     NaN
4 2018-07-03   01:00:00     95
```

Thank you all for  your help.

Comment: Your merge statement works fine for me.  I am getting back expected results.

Comment: `dti.merge(temp1, on=['Date1', 'Time1'], how='left')` works for me. Try to remove whitespaces first with `str.strip()`, and then try the merge again. Or convert them to `datetime`

Comment: Agreed, cannot reproduce (except for the additional indicator column that's not in your output, which can be achieved by removing `indicator=True`)

Comment: Do `dti['Date1'] = dti['Date1'].str.strip()` for both columns and in both dataframes.

Comment: `indicator=True` gives you an additional column that you didn't mention in your expected output, so just set it to false?  I could reproduce your code and it worked just fine